# How to check incoming bool and set private field to then be sent to Base Constructor

Tags: c#

I am not sure how to do this.

**The goal:** I want to check the incoming bool useWebServiceConnection (as you see below) and set the private field connectionString before passing it to the base constructor based on useWebServiceConnection to set the connectionString.

I think the base class constructor is called first always right?  So this is not going to work.

Right now I also get "Cannot Access Static Property in Static Context" for this line:

```
public ProjectDB(bool useWebServiceConnection) : base(connectionString)
```

**BASE CLASS:**

public class DatabaseBase
 {
  private readonly string connectionString;
  private bool useCounters;

public DatabaseBase(string connectionString)
  {
   this.connectionString = connectionString;
  }

**DERIVED CLASS:**

```
public class ProjectDB : DatabaseBase
{
    private bool useWebServiceConnection;
    private string connectionString;

private bool isWebServiceCall;

public ProjectDB(bool useWebServiceConnection) : base(connectionString)
{
    this.useWebServiceConnection = useWebServiceConnection;
    connectionString = this.useWebServiceConnection == true ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceConnectionString"] : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConnectionString"];
}

private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
```

**The Derived class originally worked like this before I changed what you see above (we have had it working like this until the need to check a bool and change connection strings whenever needed):**

```
public class ProjectDB : DatabaseBase
{

    readonly static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConnectionString"];

    public ProjectDB() : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

**UPDATED:**  Here's what I came up with.  Look at the original vs. what I tried vs. what I came up with based off your help:

```
public class ProjectDB : DatabaseBase
 {
    readonly static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConnectionString"];

    private bool useWebServiceConnection;

     private bool isWebServiceCall;

    public ProjectDB() : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public ProjectDB(bool useWebServiceConnection) : base(useWebServiceConnection
            ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceConnectionString"]
            : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConnectionString"])
    {

    }
```

Notice that I have a local connectionString field in the derived class.  That's so existing code can just call and instantiate ProjectDB() without passing in any value and that means it will just use the default DB conneciton string "SomeOtherConnection" as it's initialized ast the top of the derived class as you can see.

We also have the 2nd overloaded constructor now.  With your help, now I have the option of specifying whether to use a special service connection string when I create a new ProjectDB object.

I think this is a good solution.  If not, or if you have an even better cleaner impelementation in mind let me know but I learned some good ideas and didn't know I could sort of forward that local constructor's param to the base constructor like this so thanks a lot...now I know.

One thing though, I don't really need a local backing field useWebServiceConnection now that I've just passed it through to my base class's constructor.  So this comes obsolete so I removed it from the constructor:

```
this.useWebServiceConnection = useWebServiceConnection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class DatabaseBase
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    private bool useCounters;

    public DatabaseBase(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return connectionString; }
    }
}

public class ProjectDB : DatabaseBase
{
    private bool useWebServiceConnection;
    private bool isWebServiceCall;

    public ProjectDB(bool useWebServiceConnection)
        : base(
            useWebServiceConnection
                ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceConnectionString"]
                : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeOtherConnectionString"])
    {
        this.useWebServiceConnection = useWebServiceConnection;
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: then what's the point of setting this.useWebServiceConnection = useWebServiceConnection; if I've satisfied my requirement by sending the check through as a param to the base constructor?

Comment: I just left that because you had it there. I thought you might have some future use for it planned. I'd remove if I were you, since it can be added back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ProjectDB(bool useWebServiceConnection) 
    : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[useWebServiceConnection ? "ServiceConnectionString" : "SomeOtherConnectionString"])
{
    this.useWebServiceConnection = useWebServiceConnection;
}
```

Comment: not liking this approach. I want to set it to a variable first for easy debugging and this just looks long.

Comment: Also, isn't the useWebServiceConnection set after the base would be called?  So useWebServiceConnection wouldn't even be set yet right?

Comment: @coffeeaddict: If it behaves like C++, it will be valid because it's passed in as part of the constructor arguments. He didn't use this.useWebServiceConnection.

Answer (score 0):

The base has to be constructed before the derived class as the derived may be dependent on that. There are a few approaches you can take here:

1. Supply a setter for the value and have the derived set it.
2. Make the connectionString protected so that the derived can set it directly and allow the default constructor.
3. Externalize the information into application settings and retrieve as needed rather than carrying them around in the classes.
4. Add it to the derived constructor as well. Of course, that probably changes the flow a little, you'd have to decide outside of your class.

Comment: (Externalize the information into application settings ).  I can't just set it externally, it's not a one scenario situation  that's why I am checking the flag to determine which connection string to pass to the Base. And I don't get your #1 or #3.  setter on what?  I need

Comment: I want to require the useWebServiceConnection to be set via a constructor so nobody can miss it.  And I want the connectionString to be passed to the base to be set based on logic that checks useWebServiceConnection bool.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Then I think option 1 or 2 is what you have. Personally, I'd go with 2 unless there's a compelling reason to not allow the derived class to use the connection string.

Comment: making the base's connectionString protected doesn't get rid of the error "Cannot Access Static Property in Static Context"